# Symfony don't save manual login

Tags: php, symfony

I have create a manual in-code login method. The function at the page works.

The profiler says I am correctly authenticated.

But Symfony does not save the session / the login correct. If I visit a page they is only for ROLE_USER, I get the `Full authentication is required to access this resource.` Message and the user in the previous login was not saved (Symfony use anonymous token).

Here my login action:

```php
namespace ###HIDDEN###\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User;

class AutoLoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/auto-login")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {

            $user = new User("Marcel", null, array('ROLE_USER'));

            $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, "main", $user->getRoles());

            $this->get("security.token_storage")->setToken($token);

            $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
            $this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);

            return new Response("<body>Logging in!</body>");
        }

        return new Response("<body>You already logged in!</body>");
    }
}
```

I am using Symfony 2.8 LTS version.

Comment: You are checking for the `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` role. Check if your profiler lists the correct roles. Does your user implement the `UserInterface` correctly?

Comment: This was my issue. I have now implement an `UserInterface` and an `UserProvider`. It does works now. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! All the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `User` class implements the `UserInterface` ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#create-your-user-entity)).

It must return the roles a user has, either statically or set from a persistent storage like a database.

Also remember to check the Web Profiler to see the authentication details, and the granted roles to the current authenticated user.